# How to add items to JSTL <form:select> tag from jquery?

Tags: jquery, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl, jsp-tags

Iam having a JSTL select tag in jsp page.I need to fill data to it from jquery.How to do this?Please help.Thanks in advance!

```
<form:select path="levels" id="level">
</form:select>
```

Comment: can you please share what have you tried? share your jquery code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jquery doesn't operate at the JSTL level.  The JSTL you've got here will execute first and create a normal  tag in your html/DOM.  Then you will be able to use jquery to manipulate.

```
<form:select path="levels" id="level">
</form:select>

$("#level").append('<option value=1>Option 1</option>');
```